# Why does greedy.c keep telling me my result is unused?

Tags: c, cs50

Hey everyone i was wondering if anyone can help me on this

```
while(q < x) 
{ 
    x - q; count++; 
}
```

it keeps telling me that the result of `x - q` is unused

Comment: x-d or x-q? you just did the calculation without using the result. and if q < x, the loop'd run forever because x and q are not changed in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

you just calculate `x-q` and do nothing with result of this operation. You have to store somewhere result of operation. Just by *guessing* what you try to do, I think you have to write:

```
while(q < x)
{
    x = x - q;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation `x - q` will indeed compute the result of subtracting `q` from `x` (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize that line out since it doesn't do anything useful) but the result will not be stored anywhere.

What you need to do is:

```
x = x - q;
```

Or, for brevity:

```
x -= q;
```

Assuming you meant to put the result of `x - q` back into `x`.